# Why UIView size is changed by adding label on it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I have `Manager UIViewController` class. `Draw Chart UIView` is one of the components in `Manager ViewController`. It is shown in the attached picture.
In `Manager.m`, I set the size of `DrawChart UIView`.

```
- (IBAction)viewRecordButtonisPressed:(id)sender {
    //set UIView size 
    CGRect frame = self.drawChart.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    frame.origin.y = (int)((float)self.view.bounds.size.height/6.0);
    frame.size.width = self.view.bounds.size.width;
    frame.size.height = (int)((float)self.view.bounds.size.height*(2.0/3.0));
    self.drawChart.frame = frame;
    self.drawChart.hidden = NO;
    [self.drawChart setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

Then in DrawChart.m, I added three labels. Then Draw Chart's UIView size is changed. How to write on UIView without changing the UIView's size?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    if(![currentNameID isEqualToString:@""]){
        [self extractInformation];
        UILabel *idLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 20)];
        [idLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [idLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [idLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Didot-Italic" size: 15.0f]];
        NSString* idtext = @"ID: ";
        idLabel.text = [idtext stringByAppendingString:currentNameID];
        [self addSubview:idLabel];

        UILabel *dobLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 300, 20)];
        [dobLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [dobLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [dobLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Didot-Italic" size: 15.0f]];
        idtext = @"DOB: ";
        dobLabel.text = [idtext stringByAppendingString:dob];
        [self addSubview:dobLabel];

        UILabel *genderLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 20)];
        [genderLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [genderLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [genderLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Didot-Italic" size: 15.0f]];
        idtext = @"Gender: ";
        genderLabel.text = [idtext stringByAppendingString:gender];
        [self addSubview:genderLabel];
        }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is. The way I solved is I used CoreGraphic to write text. It doesn't change the UIView's size.
I replaced with

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    if(![currentNameID isEqualToString:@""]){
        [self extractInformation];
        NSDictionary *textAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName: @"Didot-Italic" size: 15.0f], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]};

        // Create string drawing context
        NSStringDrawingContext *drawingContext = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
        CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 20);
        NSString* idtext = @"ID: ";
        idtext = [idtext stringByAppendingString:currentNameID];
        [idtext drawWithRect:drawRect
                     options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                  attributes:textAttributes
                     context:drawingContext];

        CGRect drawRect1 = CGRectMake(10, 30, 300, 20);
        idtext = @"DOB: ";
        idtext = [idtext stringByAppendingString:dob];
        [idtext drawWithRect:drawRect1
                     options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                  attributes:textAttributes
                     context:drawingContext];

        CGRect drawRect2 = CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 20);
        idtext = @"Gender: ";
        idtext = [idtext stringByAppendingString:gender];
        [idtext drawWithRect:drawRect2
                     options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                  attributes:textAttributes
                     context:drawingContext];

    }
}
```